# Php DateTime::setDate() not working on first DatePeriod iteration

Tags: php, datetime

In some reporting I'm looping through the next 6 months and figuring out a start/end ranges to do calculations with. For each month this loops through, setDate() works correctly EXCEPT for the first month.

```
# Loop over the next 6 months (from start of this month)
$now = new DateTime("first day of this month", new DateTimeZone("Pacific/Auckland"));

$end = clone $now;
$end->modify("+6 month");

$int = new DateInterval("P1M");
$period = new DatePeriod($now, $int, $end);

# For each month, work out the start/end dates and times for the reports
foreach ($period as $month) {
    $start = clone $month;
    $start->setDate($start->format("Y"), $start->format("m"), 1);
    $start->setTime(0, 0, 0);

    $end = clone $month;
    $end->setDate($end->format("Y"), $end->format("m"), $end->format("t"));
    $end->setTime(23, 23, 59);

    # Dumping out data here shows weirdness below
}
```

No matter what, the first month end comes out as the 1st. Even if I manually set it to any other valid day integer. I've stripped this to the bare example and it's still doing it.

```
string(19) "2016-05-01 00:00:00"
string(19) "2016-05-01 23:23:59" <- Huh? This should be 31
===========
string(19) "2016-06-01 00:00:00"
string(19) "2016-06-30 23:23:59"
===========
string(19) "2016-07-01 00:00:00"
string(19) "2016-07-31 23:23:59"
...etc...
```

I'm on php 5.5.26

Comment: [Duplicated](https://eval.in/577274)

Comment: If I change `"first day of this month"` to `'2016-05-01 00:00:00'` or `null` it works as expected, in case this gives anyone any idea.

Comment: It also works if you do: `$now->setDate($now->format("Y"), $now->format("m"), 1);
$period = new DatePeriod('R6/'.$now->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s').'Z/P1M');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63863

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## Bug in PHP when creating a DateTime object using certain [relative formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php).
>
> [PHP Bug #63863   DateTime:setDate() date not used after modify("last day of...")](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63863)
>
> This seems to happen only when using certain relative formats to create the DateTime object, such as `'last day of next month'` or `'first day of this month'`, however `'last sat of July 2008'` **does not** cause the error.

Thanks to [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811240/mike) in the comments.

## Simple workaround, use a different approach to creating the intial `$now` DateTime object.

https://eval.in/577984

```
# Loop over the next 6 months (from start of this month)
$now = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Pacific/Auckland"));
$now->setDate($now->format("Y"), $now->format("m"), 1);

$end = clone $now;
$end->modify("+6 month");

$int = new DateInterval("P1M");
$period = new DatePeriod($now, $int, $end);

# For each month, work out the start/end dates and times for the reports
foreach ($period as $month) {
    $start = clone $month;
    $start->setDate($start->format("Y"), $start->format("m"), 1);
    $start->setTime(0, 0, 0);

    $end = clone $month;
    $end->setDate($end->format("Y"), $end->format("m"), $end->format("t"));
    $end->setTime(23, 23, 59);

    echo $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
    echo $end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
}
```

Comment: obviously the usage of `new` there should be optimized, and I'm still curious what is actually causing that behavior.

Comment: Actually it's not a bug in the cloning, it's a bug in the original object when created using certain [relative formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) such as 'last day of next month' or 'first day of this month' (Bug report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63863).

Comment: @Mike Ahh! Now it all makes sense. Good find, and thank you. (editied)

Comment: Thanks Mike & Tony :)